# Change UID for watchdog message

Tags: 8, log-messages

In Drupal 8 with DbLog logger, I am trying to log some audit messages to a different user than the currently logged-in user. Unfortunately, it looks like something is overwriting my context.

I tried `\Drupal::logger("proreos")->info("bla", ['uid' => 5]);` and `\Drupal::logger("proreos")->info("bla", ['user' => User::load(5)]);`, but neither of them worked. In both the cases, the current user ID was instead used.

How can I use a different user ID?

To clarify: This is not about logging another uid, it is about assigning the row in watchdog to a different user.

Answer (score 1):

Logger will always log for the current user, except you provide your own logging service.

The context is used to replace placeholders in the message, see [here](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-3-logger-interface.md), so to get the userid in the message, use this:

```
\Drupal::logger("proreos")->info("bla @uid", array('@uid' => 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is the following one.

```
\Drupal::logger("proreos")->info("bla %uid", ['%uid' => 5]);
```

This is similar to what Drupal does in [`user_cancel()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_cancel/8.2.x).

```
  if (!$account) {
    drupal_set_message(t('The user account %id does not exist.', array('%id' => $uid)), 'error');
    \Drupal::logger('user')->error('Attempted to cancel non-existing user account: %id.', array('%id' => $uid));
    return;
  }
```

Consider the first and the second argument of `error()` or `info()` as the first two arguments of [`t()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/8.2.x).

Comment: The user ID in the watchdog table will still be of the current user.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you all. I appreciate that watchdog is not the correct table for my needs. I have created my own audit table and logging service now.